# How to make smooth rotation

Tags: ios, animation, rotatetransform

I want to make smooth rotation of a compass, like i have in my Android app :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/md93ys92938njaf/2014-07-31%2012.24.19.mov

To be the same in my iOS app

However this is my current state: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kk6l3atkg7oc0k2/VID_20140731_122703.mp4

```
-(void)rotate:(UIView *)v angle:(float)angle{

    CGFloat duration = 0.5;//animated ? 0.5 : 0.01;

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    animation.fromValue = [[v.layer presentationLayer] valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    animation.toValue = @(angle);
    animation.duration = duration;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.repeatCount = 0;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    [v.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.60)];
    [v.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{



    float oldRad =  -manager.heading.magneticHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;

    float newRad =  -newHeading.magneticHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;


    [self rotate:_myLocationButton.imageView angle:newHeading.magneticHeading];
    LogInfo(@"%f (%f) => %f (%f)", manager.heading.trueHeading, oldRad, newHeading.trueHeading, newRad);

}
```

How to make the rotation smoother, and around the center point of the star ?

EDIT:
the actual problem:1. it rotates TOO QUICKLY
                   2. it stops in the wrong position

see video https://www.dropbox.com/s/lv4uyhe7oidq5m3/VID_20140731_133116.mp4

edit:

log output values:

```
2014-07-31 14:24:10.702 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController rotate:fromAgnle:angle:]:160

previousValue:-0.504699 newValue:-0.999089

2014-07-31 14:24:10.704 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController locationManager:didUpdateHeading:]:151

manager.heading.trueheading: 61.573509 (oldRad: -0.999089) => newHeading.trueHeading:61.573509 (newRad:-0.999089)

2014-07-31 14:24:10.705 App[1040:60b] D,-[Prefs getLocation]:81

coordinate:31.2719341228076,34.83940961773958

2014-07-31 14:24:14.525 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController rotate:fromAgnle:angle:]:160

previousValue:-0.999089 newValue:-0.909013

2014-07-31 14:24:14.527 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController locationManager:didUpdateHeading:]:151

manager.heading.trueheading: 56.412567 (oldRad: -0.909013) => newHeading.trueHeading:56.412567 (newRad:-0.909013)

2014-07-31 14:24:14.528 App[1040:60b] D,-[Prefs getLocation]:81

coordinate:31.2719341228076,34.83940961773958

2014-07-31 14:24:14.759 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController rotate:fromAgnle:angle:]:160

previousValue:-0.828879 newValue:-0.724668

2014-07-31 14:24:14.761 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController locationManager:didUpdateHeading:]:151

manager.heading.trueheading: 45.850368 (oldRad: -0.724668) => newHeading.trueHeading:45.850368 (newRad:-0.724668)

2014-07-31 14:24:14.763 App[1040:60b] D,-[Prefs getLocation]:81

coordinate:31.2719341228076,34.83940961773958

2014-07-31 14:24:18.406 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController rotate:fromAgnle:angle:]:160

previousValue:-0.724668 newValue:-0.814539

2014-07-31 14:24:18.408 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController locationManager:didUpdateHeading:]:151

manager.heading.trueheading: 50.999573 (oldRad: -0.814539) => newHeading.trueHeading:50.999573 (newRad:-0.814539)

2014-07-31 14:24:18.409 App[1040:60b] D,-[Prefs getLocation]:81

coordinate:31.2719341228076,34.83940961773958

2014-07-31 14:24:18.553 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController rotate:fromAgnle:angle:]:160

previousValue:-0.460764 newValue:-0.912728

2014-07-31 14:24:18.555 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController locationManager:didUpdateHeading:]:151

manager.heading.trueheading: 56.625385 (oldRad: -0.912728) => newHeading.trueHeading:56.625385 (newRad:-0.912728)

2014-07-31 14:24:18.556 App[1040:60b] D,-[Prefs getLocation]:81

coordinate:31.2719341228076,34.83940961773958

2014-07-31 14:24:18.963 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController rotate:fromAgnle:angle:]:160

previousValue:-0.912728 newValue:-1.015497

2014-07-31 14:24:18.965 App[1040:60b] I,-[WBGoogleMapViewController locationManager:didUpdateHeading:]:151

manager.heading.trueheading: 62.513649 (oldRad: -1.015497) => newHeading.trueHeading:62.513649 (newRad:-1.015497)

2014-07-31 14:24:18.966 App[1040:60b] D,-[Prefs getLocation]:81

coordinate:31.2719341228076,34.83940961773958
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)rotate:(UIView *)v fromAngle:(float)from angle:(float)angle{

    if( from == angle){
        return;
    }
//to keep rotation in the same direction
    if(abs(toRad(from)-toRad(angle))>=6){
        if(from>angle){
            angle +=360;
            LogTrace(@"add");
        }else {
            angle-=360;
            LogTrace (@"subtract");
        }
    }


    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    animation.fromValue = @(-toRad(from));
    animation.toValue = @(-toRad(angle));
    LogInfo(@"from:%f to:%f",-toRad(from),-toRad(angle));
    animation.duration = 0.0f;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.repeatCount = 0;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    [v.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.494)];
    [v.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do with below code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _mapTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
        _mapScrollView.transform = _mapTransform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

But maintain the current angle of view so when you will invoke the method to rotate by an angle then you can get the difference of angle that needs to be rotated.

Comment: I don't want to transform the map -> but the little star inside the green square

Comment: Just use the reference of little start (v) in place of _mapScrollView and _mapTransform is a reference of CGAffineTransform.

Actually I have used above code to rotate whole map so just posted same code here.

Comment: this does not work the way i want it, it rotates it on the Z axis as well, so it becomes thinner, fatter and so on. I want it to rotate around the center point of the circle of the star, without changing its width/height attributes in the process

Comment: @DhawalDwar can you check edited post video ? what can i do to make the spin slower and stop in the correct location ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting -

```
[v.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.50)];
```

instead of -

```
[v.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.60)];
```

Comment: the north pin of the star is taller than the rest of the star. I want a smooth rotation around the center of the circle of the star, my object is elliptic, its center is not 0.5 on the y axis

Comment: my actual problem is the jumps

Comment: can you check updated post video, what can I do to make the rotation smoother (slower and stops in correct place)

Comment: can you tell me the angle values you are getting

Comment: try one thing rotate myLocationButton instead of its image. and set anchor point to center ..

Comment: rotating the locationButton looks worse